# using ffmpeg to convert a set of YUV images to a video?

Tags: ffmpeg, h.264, yuv

I am trying to use ffmpeg to convert a set of YUV frames to a mp4 video. 
I have a set of YUV frames which named as (each one is an image) :
YUV1.yuv 
YUV2.yuv
.
.
YUv15.yuv
The code is:

```
ffmpeg -s 3840x2160 -pix_fmt yuv420p -i YUV%d.yuv -vcodec libx264 -r 30 -s 3840x2160 output.mp4
```

It shows that the YUV%d.yuv no such file or directory. 
I know the png or jpeg or  bmp can be named as Img%d.png/jpeg/bmp but perhaps can not be used for .yuv. 
So is there any way to input a set of yuv images in ffmpeg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ffmpeg`'s wildcard syntax doesn't work on yuv or other video formats, I guess. You could concat them just like:

```sh
cat *.yuv > all.yuv  
# or cat `ls |grep "\d*.yuv"` > all.yuv if you like
# or any other complex commands to get the file list
ffmpeg -i all.yuv -c:v libx264 ...
```

[Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20124553/converting-more-yuv-frames-to-one-yuv-frame)

Comment: You can skip the file creation (and stream props have to be signalled): `cat *.yuv | ffmpeg -f rawvideo -s 3840x2160 -pix_fmt yuv420p -framerate 30 -i - -c:v libx264 ...`

Comment: Thank u for ur code. I tried this code, but it alwasy shows that 'cat' is not found.

Comment: Then you should ask yourself [Is there a replacement for cat on Windows](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60244/is-there-replacement-for-cat-on-windows#60254)?

Answer (score 0):

From ffmpeg documentation:
You can use YUV files as input:

```
ffmpeg -i /tmp/test%d.Y /tmp/out.mpg
```

It will use the files:

```
/tmp/test0.Y, /tmp/test0.U, /tmp/test0.V,
/tmp/test1.Y, /tmp/test1.U, /tmp/test1.V, etc...
```

I found that i needed to use this line:

```
-r, 21, -pix_fmt, yuv420p, -s, 1280x720, -i, file.Y
```

https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Video-Options